# Change UserAgent programmatically from IE11 to IE 9

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have to open a Report using Crystal Report Viewer, when open on IE11 I got design issues but changing the user agent to IE9 will adjust the design of the report. What is the solution that can be done to change the user agent string of my page, knowing that I don't want to change the web.config of the whole website. I need a help
This is my Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="rpt.aspx.cs" Inherits="Reports_rpt" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Report</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (version = /MSIE (\d+\.\d+)/.exec(navigator.userAgent)) {
            isIE = true;
            browserVersion = parseFloat(version[1]);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="width: 800px; height: 700px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="rpt" runat="server" AutoDataBind="True" DisplayGroupTree="False"
                ToolPanelView="None" ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="~/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/CrystalReportWebFormViewer4/Images/ToolBar/" />
            <center>
                <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Style="display: block; color: orange; font-size: 15pt;" />
            </center>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Design issues"? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You can change the User agent by changing the header information in the response.  This is the only way to do it!  Which means you have to use an API to get the content.  That API must alter the header information on the get request.

Comment: Can you please give me an exemple @JohnPeters

Comment: You can't change user agent string of your client. Also you're looking into wrong direction - instead you should check support of/update the CrystalReportViewer component - to make it look pretty in newer browsers :)

Comment: @MohitJain Design issues : Opening reports that are developed using Crystal Reports via IE 11 causes layout faults and inconsistencies. Lot of spaces, wrong header position,...

Answer (score 0):

From Micorsoft's site:

```
  WebClient client = new WebClient ();

    // Add a user agent header in case the 
    // requested URI contains a query.

    client.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

    Stream data = client.OpenRead (MyHTMLFile.html);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (data);
    string s = reader.ReadToEnd ();
    Console.WriteLine (s);
    data.Close ();
    reader.Close ();
```